trouble while reading JS File
HTML code
HTML file Name index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script src="counter_funtions.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center padding">
    <div class="text-center transparent p-4">
        <div>
            <h1 class="heading">Counter</h1>
            <p class="numbers" id="counterValue">0</p>
            <div>
                <button class="button" onclick="onDecrement()">DECREASE</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="onReset()">RESET</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="onIncrement()">INCREASE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>

JS Code
JS file name counter_funtions.js
let counterElement = document.getElementById("counterValue");
console.log(counterElement);

and the output is
[Running] node "d:\JavaScipt\Project-3 Counter App\counter_funtions.js"
d:\JavaScipt\Project-3 Counter App\counter_funtions.js:1
let counterElement = document.getElementById("counterValue");
                     ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\JavaScipt\Project-3 Counter App\counter_funtions.js:1:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.12.2

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.083 seconds

trying to Run JS code expecting 0 as output.

Node? This looks like an HTML file to be viewed with a browser. Why do you mention Node? When viewed with a browser, document is not loaded when parsing the <head> element (head is parsed before the body)

Are you trying to run the JS script from a command line and this is your output, or is this coming from the console when you open the index.html file ?

@knittl Because the error message mentions node? And OP seemingly tries to run this file with node? (For whatever unknown reasons ...)

@derpirscher yes, that's exactly my question. Why does the error message mention node? Why is the (inclded) script file of a website executed with node (without a browser, without the HTML, thus without a document)? If this is a node script, the answer is simple: node doesn't have document, that only available with a browser and DOM.

@ArnaudFlaesch yes I'm trying to JS file from command line just to read the 0 element from HTML file

You can't, check my answer

The JS file does not know that it is loaded by your HTML. It could be loaded by any HTML file, how should the node runtime know which one? (apart from node not being able to render the DOM)

You don't have to use Node to do what you want, just open the HTML file, it will load the JS script and execute it. Executing it separatly with Node will cause errors because it will be executed as a server script, with no document object defined. The document object is only available in the browser.
